# How to access all created objects and update attributes

Tags: ruby, oop, object

I have a employee class where i stores employee details like age, DOB and Points earned.

```
class Employee
  attr_accessor :id, :dob, :points

  def initialize
    @id = id
    @dob = dob
    @points = points
  end

  def tranfer_points
  # Access both employee objects and add points to one and remove points from other
  end
end


emp_one = Employee.new(1,"2 Jan 1990",400)
emp_two = Employee.new(2,"12 Jan 1986",700)

emp_two.transfer()
```

I want to know what is the best practice to maintain all created objects, so that i can transfer points from one employee to other.

Should i use class variable here, would that be a good solution, is it a standard practice?

like below

```
class Employee
  @@all_employee = Hash.new
  attr_accessor :id, :dob, :points

  def initialize
    @id = id
    @dob = dob
    @points = points
    add_all_employee
  end

  def add_all_employee
    @@all_employee[id] = self
  end

  def tranfer_points(i,points)
    b = @@all_employee[i]
    self.balance -= points
    b.points += points
  end
end
```

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hi scorix, yes without DB

Comment: Why do you need a class for `Employee`? Won’t the simple `Hash` instance suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do this.

With database:

```
class Employee
  def tranfer_points_to(recipient, num_points)
    Employee.transaction do
      self.update!(points: self.points - num_points)
      recipient.update!(points: recipient.points + num_points)
    end
  end
end
```

Using [Rails Transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) would be a good way to ensure you don't accidentally update one and not the other, in case there is an exception raised inside this block.

Without database:

```
class Employee
  def tranfer_points_to(recipient, num_points)
    self.points -= num_points
    recipient.points += num_points
  end
end
```

UPDATE:
To answer your comments:

If you consider using db, then it's a no brainer, just save the model.
Without the db, it's common to use some parent class to "hold" employee instances. An example:

```
class Company
  attr_reader :employees

  def initialize
    @employees = []
  end

  def add_employee(id, dob, points)
    employees.push(Employee.new(id, dob, points))
  end

  def tranfer_points(from_employee_id, to_employee_id, num_points)
    find_employee_by_id(from_employee_id).points -= num_points
    find_employee_by_id(to_employee_id).points += num_points
  end

  def find_employee_by_id(id)
    employees.find { |e| e.id == id }
  end
end

company = Company.new
company.add_employee(1, "2 Jan 1990", 400)
company.add_employee(2, "2 Jan 1991", 400)
company.transfer_points(1, 2, 200)

company.find_employee_by_id(1).points => 200
company.find_employee_by_id(2).points => 600
```

Comment: Hi Petr, how do i find the recipient object out of the many which are created. Should i use class variable to store all employee objects created and access the object with there id? would that be a good solution

Comment: Hi Petr, i have updated my question, can you please take a look at the updated one, Thanks

Comment: @opensource-ios Okay, I think I know what you want. See edit ^^

Comment: Aweomse Petr, thanks a lot. so wont class variables work here or is its not a standard practice. Please let me know i am curious to know.

Comment: They probably would work, I just haven't seen anyone use class variables in cases like this.

Comment: Thanks Petr, upvoting

Comment: hi petr, i have posted one more question can you please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850575/undefined-method-blank-for-123string-nomethoderror

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
require 'singleton'
require 'forwardable'
require 'thread'

class EmployeeStore
  include Singleton

  class << self
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegator :instance, :employees, :employees
    def_delegator :instance, :find, :find
    def_delegator :instance, :add, :add
    def_delegator :instance, :transfer_points, :transfer_points
    def_delegator :instance, :remove, :remove
  end

  def employees
    @employees.dup
  end

  def find(id)
    @employees[id].dup
  end

  def add(employee)
    @employees[employee.id] = employee
  end

  def remove(employee)
    case employee
      when Employee
        @employees.delete(employee.id)
      when Fixnum
        @employees.delete(employee)
      else
        raise "Don't know how to delete #{employee}"
    end
  end

  def transfer_points(from, to, points)
    # EmployeeStore is the only way to modify @employees
    real_from, real_to = find(from.id), find(to.id)

    # synchronize for thread-safe
    @mutex.synchronize do
      f_points, t_points = from.points, to.points

      begin
        real_from.instance_variable_set(:@points, f_points - points)
        real_to.instance_variable_set(:@points, t_points + points)
          # do something else
      rescue
        real_from.instance_variable_set(:@points, f_points)
        real_to.instance_variable_set(:@points, t_points)
      ensure
        from.instance_variable_set(:@points, real_from.points)
        to.instance_variable_set(:@points, real_to.points)
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def initialize
    @employees = {}
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    super
  end
end

class Employee
  attr_reader :id, :dob, :points

  def initialize(id, dob, points)
    @id, @dob, @points = id, dob, points
    EmployeeStore.add(self)
  end

  def transfer_points_to(employee, points)
    EmployeeStore.transfer_points(self, employee, points)
  end
end


Employee.new(1, "2 Jan 1990", 400)
Employee.new(2, "12 Jan 1986", 700)

emp_one = EmployeeStore.find(1)
emp_two = EmployeeStore.find(2)

1.upto(10).map do
  Thread.new do
    emp_one.transfer_points_to(emp_two, 30)
  end
end.map(&:join)

p emp_one.points # => 100
p emp_two.points # => 1000
```

**Class variables are not thread-safe**