# undefined method `blank?' for "123":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am getting this strange error for a when I am checking a class variable in ruby

> undefined method `blank?' for "123":String (NoMethodError)

all I am doing is `Employee.set_id.blank?`

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: `String#blank?` is defined in Rails. not in basic ruby interpreter. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `blank?` method is defined for every Ruby object that is descendant of the `Object` class in `activesupport` gem (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb).

This gem is part of Rails framework. However, if you still want to use this utility of `activesupport` in your non-Rails Ruby project, you can require it in your source files with the sentence:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

Make sure you have installed `activesupport` gem in your system.

Comment: I got an `uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)`. So I added `require 'active_support'` above `require 'active_support/core_ext'`. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Employee.set_id.nil? || Employee.set_id.strip.empty?` instead.

`String#blank?` is defined in `ActiveSupport`

Comment: Note that `' '.blank?` is `true` whereas `' '.empty?` is `false`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks a lot